# String obtained from ResultSet does not match normally defined String of the same content

Tags: java, sql-server, string, string-comparison

I have a simulation for a hospital management system. Accompanying that is an Azure SQL server to store log information and the user access levels within the system (referred to as variable `access` in the `authorize()` method.)

I connect to the database server, use a prepared statement to find a specific record in my employee table, and retrieve a specific column which, in this specific instance, is a string containing `Doctor`.

In my `main()` method I save the return statement of the `authorize` function as `String auth`, which I use to compare to another string `Doctor` in an `if` statement. I even have the system print what is contained in `auth`, which always returns `"Doctor"`. Yet the if statement is never executed.

How can I resolve this?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
{   
    connect();
    String auth = (authorize(1083, "pass"));
    System.out.println("The authentication string is: " + auth);
    System.out.println("\nTesting to see if authentication String matches: Doctor");
    if(auth.toString().equals("Doctor"))
    {
        System.out.println("Authentication string matches!");
    }
    else System.out.println("Authenication String does not match!");
    close();
} 

public static void connect()
{
    //buffer.connect();
    try 
    {
        String server = "jdbc:sqlserver://hospital-mangement.database.windows.net:1433;database=Hospital-Mangement;user=********;password=********;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(server);
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Database connection is successful!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.toString();
    }
}

public static String authorize(int ID, String pass) throws SQLException
{
    //connect();
    ResultSet user = null;
    String access = null;
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID = ? AND Password = ?");
        
        stmt.setInt(1, ID);
        stmt.setString(2, pass);
        user = stmt.executeQuery();
        user.next();
        access = user.getString("Access_Level");
        return access;
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.toString();
    }

    //close();

    return null;  
}
```

Output that I get:

[image]

Comment: Maybe whitespace characters? Try auth.toString().Length

Comment: Good tip, I just found it out as you commented. But, doing that would have revealed the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why this was occurring. The Azure server database appended spaces to the end of the strings that I wasn't initially aware of.

Comment: Azure doesn't just add spaces for the fun of it. Probably those spaces are actually stored in the database.

Comment: Probably a fixed length string data type then, unless it's just that particular entry

Comment: I believe it is that. I set a particular length for these variables in the table creation statement. So perhaps Azure is filling up the rest of the unused character length with spaces?